# Include Tycho dependencies in Maven site

Tags: maven, tycho

I'm looking for a way to list the project dependencies managed by Tycho (version 1.0.0) in the project documentation generated by the `maven-site-plugin` (version 3.6).

Test dependencies defined in the `pom.xml` appear as usual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tycho works on P2-Repositories. Those are totally different from Maven repositories, so this is probably simply not possible.